# Gap between drawing and <canvas> boundary (using Paper.js)

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I have the following JavaScript code which fills a `<canvas>` with circles using Paper.js:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    'use strict';

    paper.install(window);
    paper.setup(document.getElementById('mainCanvas'));

    const CANVAS_WIDTH = 400;
    const CANVAS_HEIGHT = 400;

    const RADIUS = 10;
    const FILL_COLOR = 'green';

    for (let x = RADIUS; x <= CANVAS_WIDTH - RADIUS; x += 2 * RADIUS) {
        for (let y = RADIUS; y <= CANVAS_HEIGHT - RADIUS; y += 2 * RADIUS) {
            let c = Shape.Circle(x, y, RADIUS);
            c.fillColor = FILL_COLOR;
        }
    }

    paper.view.draw();
});
```

This should fill the `<canvas>` from left-to-right and top-to-bottom with no gaps on the `<canvas>` boundary. However, I get this image that has a little gap on the right and bottom:

[image: my generated canvas]

It's subtle, but compare it with the left and top boundaries, and the difference becomes clear.

Why is there this gap? How can I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

This gap is the consequence of the border applied to your canvas.
You can easily get rid of it by setting the CSS `box-sizing` property of you canvas to `border-box`.

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xidi2xidi/mp61f2nk/1/) demonstrating it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Debug Paper.js</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/acorn"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/paper"></script>
    <style>
        canvas {
            width      : 400px;
            height     : 400px;
            border     : 1px solid;
            box-sizing : border-box;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
    paper.setup('canvas');

    const CANVAS_WIDTH = 400;
    const CANVAS_HEIGHT = 400;

    const RADIUS = 10;
    const FILL_COLOR = 'green';

    for (let x = RADIUS; x <= CANVAS_WIDTH - RADIUS; x += 2 * RADIUS) {
        for (let y = RADIUS; y <= CANVAS_HEIGHT - RADIUS; y += 2 * RADIUS) {
            let c = paper.Shape.Circle(x, y, RADIUS);
            c.fillColor = FILL_COLOR;
        }
    }

    console.log('canvas width = ', paper.view.bounds.width);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```